Bootstrap 5.3 extended options for border bottom sizing
According to examples displayed on the official Bootstrap guide for borders, it appears easy to adjust the border width sizing when using the border class...
<span class="border border-1"></span>
<span class="border border-2"></span>
<span class="border border-3"></span>
<span class="border border-4"></span>
<span class="border border-5"></span>

But how can we make use of these same sizing options if we are only wanting to use border bottom, for example...
<span class="border-bottom border-1"></span>
<span class="border-bottom border-2"></span>
<span class="border-bottom border-3"></span>
<span class="border-bottom border-4"></span>
<span class="border-bottom border-5"></span>


Is there something I can write in my custom .scss file to extend the utilities.scss file (node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss)  to allow border bottoms to have different border sizes?
I tried

$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "border-width": (
      property: border-width,
      class: border,
      values: $border-widths
    )
  )
);



and

    $utilities: map-merge($utilities,
    ("border-width": map-merge(map-get($utilities, "border-width"),
        (values: (
      1: 1px,
      2: 2px,
      3: 3px,
      4: 4px,
      5: 5px,
      ),
      ),
    )));


But no gravy when used in conjunction with border-bottom.
But even if I were successful at finding a solution...the following Bootstrap rule out of the utilities.scss file, has an important statement applied to its rule...

Is there any way to win this?
The only thing  I can think of is if we setup a switch case ( SASS map) or multiple if else statement process to change the value of --bs-border-width, depending on the name of the class...? I have no clue.

Thanks tdy!  You are right. That is sure verbose.  My hope is to have a more simplistic approach this way I can teach someone else how to apply this where needed in the coding structure.  I wouldn't mind doing that if it were just me.  I'll pocket that as a last emergency step.

border-bottom border-5 works just fine on my end. I suggest you have something in your CSS that overrides these class names / applies a different border width to the elements you are trying to style.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-2">
  <h2 class="border-bottom border-1 border-secondary p-2">Border bottom 1</h2>
  <h2 class="border-bottom border-2 border-danger p-2">Border bottom 2</h2>
  <h2 class="border-bottom border-3 border-success p-2">Border bottom 3</h2>
  <h2 class="border-bottom border-4 border-primary p-2">Border bottom 4</h2>
  <h2 class="border-bottom border-5 border-warning p-2">Border bottom 5</h2>
</div>




I have no clue what happened earlier, but applying your example works in my environment OOTB.  Obviously something was missed or overlooked on my end.  Many thanks!

How do u achieve border 1px left/right/top with border bottom 5px with bootstrap classes e,g, border: 1px 1px 5px 1px?

As above class="border border-1 border-bottom border-5" doesn't work for me

It doesn't work?! There's a working code snippet above.
